# How to rotate Graphics in Java

Tags: java, graphics, rotation

I have drawn some Graphics in a `JPanel`, like circles, rectangles, etc.

But I want to draw some Graphics rotated a specific degree amount, like a rotated ellipse. What should I do?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you are using plain `Graphics`, cast to `Graphics2D` first:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
```

To rotate an entire `Graphics2D`:

```
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees));
//draw shape/image (will be rotated)
```

To reset the rotation (so you only rotate one thing):

```
AffineTransform old = g2d.getTransform();
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees));
//draw shape/image (will be rotated)
g2d.setTransform(old);
//things you draw after here will not be rotated
```

Example:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        AffineTransform old = g2d.getTransform();
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees));
        //draw shape/image (will be rotated)
        g2d.setTransform(old);
        //things you draw after here will not be rotated
    }
}
```

Comment: Thans you very much and How to trasnlate a new position from old AffineTransform ?

Comment: @KidLet This might help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html You can use `rotate`, `scale`, and `translate`.

Answer (score 3):

In your `paintComponent()` overridden method, cast the Graphics argument to Graphics2D, call [`rotate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#rotate%28double%29) on this Graphics2D, and draw your ellipse.